# Python Beginner: Handling file path in script call using sys.argv[

Tags: python-3.x, escaping

to find a way to run through a bunch of subfolders to find and move special filetypes to another destination, I thought about using python.

I am working on OSX running Python 3.

I want to run my script as follows:

```
$python3 find_files.py <search_path> <destination_path> <file_extension>
```

e.g.:

```
$python3 find_files.py /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/xyz/Downloads/ /Volumes/Data/Files/ zip
```

Unfortunately I am absolutely not sure how to handle spaces in the file path.

Here is my script:

```
import os, sys, shutil

def find_files(path, destination, extension):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(extension):
                shutil.move(repr(path)+file, repr(destination)+file)

find_files(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

The moving of the files is not working due to problems with the file path.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

I already tried to do stuff like

```
form_path = path.replace(' ', '\')
```

or

```
sys.argv[1] = sys.argv[1].replace(' ', '\\')
```

to escape the spaces, but I always get the FileNotFound error.

Could anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Gardinero

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but i would say using the bash terminal would probably be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is not with space escaping but rather your program; you aren't appending root to the file you want to move (you cant just append path to it because you are walking subdirectories). Try this:

```
import os, sys, shutil

def find_files(path, destination, extension):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(extension):
                shutil.move(root + '/' + file, destination + '/' + file)


find_files(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```